# Is there an R code to remove duplicate events of same id with two -three different column conditions?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with thousands of ids with several events per id and enrollment dates, course and record.  Course is categorical, module1, module2, module3, molude4, module5 and withdrawn(any module). For example few rows looks like below

```
id  event   enrolment date  Enrolment to    course   record
1   42      2012-07-01      2013-06-30      module 5    2
1   42      2018-07-01      2019-06-30    **module 4**  1
1   43      2012-07-01      2013-06-30      module 5    2
1   43      2018-07-01      2019-06-30    **module 4**  1
2   50      2017-04-01      2018-03-31    **module 5**  2
2   50      2017-07-01      2018-03-31      module 4    1
2   34      2017-04-01      2018-03-31    **module 5**  2
2   34      2017-07-01      2018-03-31      module 4    1
3   23      2014-08-20      2015-07-20      module 5    1
3   23      2014-08-20      2015-07-20      module 4    2
3   23      2015-07-04      2016-06-04  **withdrawn**   3
4   13      2017-09-01      2018-08-01      module 4    1
4   13      2017-09-01      2018-08-01  **module 5**    2
4   23      2017-09-01      2018-08-01      module 4    1
4   23      2017-09-01      2018-08-01  **module 5**    2
```

I would like to retain 2nd,4th,5th,7th,11th,13th, & 15th row in
the data frame (education) 
I tried factoring **course** which wrongly assigns module 5 for events 42 & 43 and if I go by **max date** then it wrongly assigns module 4 to events 50 & 34

I would like data to look like below

```
id  event   status_date Course  record
1   42  2018-07-01  module 4    1
1   43  2018-07-01  module 4    1
2   50  2017-04-01  module 5    2
2   34  2016-04-01  module 5    2
3   23  2015-07-04  withdrawn   3
4   13  2017-09-01  module 5    2
4   23  2017-09-01  module 5    2
```

Comment: Sorry, not clear about the logic to retain the rows. Can you explain **why** 2nd,4th,5th,7th,11th,13th, & 15th need to be retained ?

Comment: its a bit complicated. if the date is same then I want module 5 to retain. but if dates do not match then in some cases retain module 5 even though enrolled earlier.  and in some cases max date

Comment: need latest course

Comment: Can you define "some" as well ? because it is difficult to help without completely understanding the logic on which filtering is based. In which case would you retain module 5 and in which case you retain max date ?

Comment: a person can be enrolled in 4 and 5 at the same time or 4 1st and 5 later and may 1) continue with both in that case pick 5

Comment: 3 different logics need to be met; sorry it is confusing and complicated

Comment: logic being confusing and complicated is not an issue if it is clear. So for first case (event 42), why you select module 4 when module 5 is present as well whereas for event 50 you select module 5. I guess there should be some timeframe involved as well to know if a course is currently enrolled or not?

Comment: in the the event of 42 the person's enrollment ended in 2013; enrollment duration is roughly one year for all rows; should I add that column as well

Comment: added enrollment to column, thanks

Comment: @Sunita take your first dataset, and go row by row. Do you include it or not? Then say why you include each row.... Maybe then we can figure out the pattern you are trying to explain.

Comment: I would suggest you to include all your conditions which is scattered in the comments to include it in the original post so the people who are trying to help you can get all the information at one place instead of going through each comment individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood all the requirements clearly here is a function which selects the correct date in each group

```
library(dplyr)

select_dates <- function(start, end, course) {
    #If there is same date return course with "module5"
    if (n_distinct(start) == 1)
       which.max(course == "module5")
    else {
      #Get courses which are currently enrolled
      inds <- max(start) < end
      #If any course has "module5" and no "withdrawn"
      if (any(course[inds] == "module5") & all(course[inds] != "withdrawn")) 
            #return the course with "module5" which is currently enrolled
            which.max(inds & course == "module5")
      else
            #return the currently enrolled course with a max date
            which.max(start == max(start[inds]))
         }
}
```

We then apply it for each `id` and `event`

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(enrolment_date, Enrolment_to), as.Date) %>%
  group_by(id, event) %>%
  slice(select_dates(enrolment_date, Enrolment_to, course))

#     id event enrolment_date Enrolment_to course    record
#  <int> <int> <date>         <date>       <chr>      <int>
#1     1    42 2018-07-01     2019-06-30   module4        1
#2     1    43 2018-07-01     2019-06-30   module4        1
#3     2    34 2017-04-01     2018-03-31   module5        2
#4     2    50 2017-04-01     2018-03-31   module5        2
#5     3    23 2015-07-04     2016-06-04   withdrawn      3
#6     4    13 2017-09-01     2018-08-01   module5        2
#7     4    23 2017-09-01     2018-08-01   module5        2
```

Note that you need to change the strings in the function (`"module5"` and `"withdrawn"`) and the column names (`enrolment_date` and `Enrolment_to`) based on what you have in your data.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), event = c(42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 50L, 50L, 
34L, 34L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 13L, 13L, 23L, 23L), enrolment_date = c("2012-07-01", 
"2018-07-01", "2012-07-01", "2018-07-01", "2017-04-01", "2017-07-01", 
"2017-04-01", "2017-07-01", "2014-08-20", "2014-08-20", "2015-07-04", 
"2017-09-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-01"), Enrolment_to = c("2013-06-30", 
"2019-06-30", "2013-06-30", "2019-06-30", "2018-03-31", "2018-03-31", 
"2018-03-31", "2018-03-31", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-20", "2016-06-04", 
"2018-08-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-01"), course = c("module5", 
"module4", "module5", "module4", "module5", "module4", "module5", 
"module4", "module5", "module4", "withdrawn", "module4", "module5", 
"module4", "module5"), record = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```